# Is it possible to change background colour and other visual attributes of Slider Control in Excel (via VBA or otherwise)?

Tags: excel, vba, activexobject

I have been trying to change sliders' background color using VBA:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard").Slider21.BackColor = "xxxxx"
```

but have an error saying `Object doesn't support this property or method`

Comment: Would it be `...Slider21.Fill.BackColor`?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry cybujan, doesn't look as though the slider control has any colour properties within VBA, although it does have a `Background` property in the vb.net version, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.slider_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.background(v=vs.110).aspx).

[image]